# How do I print C variables in LLDB Debugger?

Tags: c, xcode, lldb

I'm working in Xcode 4 and I want to print, in the debugger, variables like `int`s, `char`s, arrays, custom `struct`s, etc.  Is this possible?

With Objective-C I could do something like:

```c
int three = 3;
```

```
> po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", three];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`po` stands for Print Object, which essentially calls the `description` method on the object.

Use `p` to print an integer. For example:

```
p three
```

Comment: also, if it cannot resolve the type of the variable you are trying to print, try `p (int) three` forcing it to format the variable as you know it is

Comment: lol, you've got to be kidding! wondered how to do it for a solid few months but never bothered to chase it. easy when you know haha